# How do I make a dynamic 'Mass Update' Inventory Item images from File Cabinet using Formula field?

Tags: image, formula, netsuite, assign

I want to perform a mass update that will provide all my Item Inventory entity records with a selected image (possibly that follows a particular file type).

The file cabinet looks like this below:

[image: File Cabinet]

From the above, the ITEM-A, ITEM-B, ITEM-C and ITEM-D folders named after Inventory Items which are values for the "Item Code" field which can be called upon as `{itemid}`.

So far, I went to `Lists > Mass Update > Mass Updates` then navigated under ACTION to `General Updates > Items > Inventory Item` so that when I click the `Mass Update Fields` tab, I can then toggle on the checkbox under the Image data type field called "Product Image" (which is a standard NetSuite field).

To the right is the formula field. As I was looking into this, it claims that the formula field can support SQL functions so that it can perform dynamic mathematical calculations and functions specific to my needs.

I tried the following formulas to no success:

- `CONCAT(CONCAT('Products/', {itemid}), '/')`
- `CONCAT(CONCAT('Products :', {itemid}), ' : ')`
- `CONCAT(CONCAT('Products >', {itemid}), ' > ')`
- `CONCAT(CONCAT('Products/', {itemid}), CONCAT('/', ?))`
- `CONCAT(CONCAT('Products : ', {itemid}), CONCAT(' : ', %))`
- `CONCAT(CONCAT('Products > ', {itemid}), CONCAT(' > ', %))`
- `{url}`

There must be another symbol or variable using the curly bracketed notation {} to call forth internal IDs of folders within a specific directory or subdirectories.

My expected output for the Mass Update might be (at least one of them):

- `Products/ITEM-A/image.jpg`
- `Products > ITEM-A > image.jpg`
- `Products : ITEM-A : image.jpg`

or something like... (this link below isn't an actual image)

- `https://????????.app.netsuite.com/core/media/media.nl?id=####&c=????????&h=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

I made sure the images are available without login, but for confidentiality purposes, I altered the url above.

Alternatively, is there a different means to input a file cabinet structure into the formula field that can let me select a file for the "Product Image" field?

This would much be appreciated.

Comment: Using mass update script  to achieve your needs. you have the file id of the products.

Comment: I think you have to know the image description in products page right. if my understanding is wrong pls elaborate your need.

Comment: @PraveenKumar This has nothing to do with image's description. I want to assign an image to an item inventory in NetSuite using their provided field that stores images per item inventory. It is not practical to assign one image at a time to all products.